# How can I report misplaced portals in Ingress?

Tags: ingress

Yesterday a lot of new portals appeared. Some of them are misplaced more than a hundred meters. How do I report those and supply a better position?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can report an issue about portal locations at [Ingress Support Page](http://support.google.com/ingress), press `Contact Us` then choose `Report an issue with a portal`. Then, report your issue ;)

**EDIT 03/12/2013** : As mentionned by @Ilari Kajaste in comment, this way send you back to the mobile client.

To report a misplaced portal location, you'll have to go to this portal (or get a key of it) and :

1. click on the portal photo.
2. Then, click on the <kbd>EDIT</kbd> button
3. Select <kbd>EDIT TITLE</kbd>, <kbd>ADD/EDIT DESCRIPTION</kbd> or <kbd>EDIT LOCATION</kbd>
4. Enter the correct title or description, or when editing location, touch and drag the map until the marker is in the correct location.
5. Touch <kbd>SEND</kbd> to confirm your correction.
6. Wait for Niantic to make a decision about your suggestion.

Comment: FWIW, I did this a while ago and didn't get a response for over a month. However, when they did get to it they moved the portal with little fuss.

Comment: This is no longer true. The support page currently directs to the mobile client instead:

"You can report [...] Portals [...] via your scanner:

Launch the Ingress app ->
Touch the Portal you'd like to report ->
Touch the Portal's photo to bring up the detailed information screen ->
Touch EDIT, and select the type of invalid Portal report or edit you'd like to submit"

Comment: @IlariKajaste : right, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can open the portal screen, and click the triangle with the exclamation mark in it.

You then have a choice as to what you want to report. Be aware that it can take some time for Niantic to actually update the portal.

(And I mean a really long time)